# Why does AKS use more resources than a Web App Service on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-aks

I am creating a new web site using Visual Studio 2019 .Net Core 3 and React + Redux. It is one of the templates that comes with VS2019.

I need to be able to access the site from a mobile browser on my phone / simulator and debug the back end of the site while doing so.

When I looked at the default options for debugging I noticed that Web App on Azure wasn't there, but AKS is there as a default.

So I logged into my Azure account and set up a new AKS. I don't want to spend any money on it while developing, so I chose the cheapest one I could find which is about $35/month.

I went to deploy it and got an error. I submitted a ticket and the response was that the small AKS server doesn't have enough resources to host the site. They told me I would have to choose a more expensive SKU. The next step up I found was $50/month. Ouch!

At this point the site is just the unmodified hello world app from the template.

I then created a standard Web App resource in my Azure account like I have done many times. I chose the FREE Wep App.

I deployed to this web app and attached the debugger and it worked great.

So my question is what is it about AKS that makes it so that a $35/month AKS resource can't handle the most basic hello world web app that the FREE web app service can handle easily?

Comment: AKS is a cluster, this is why it's "expensive"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, AKS gives you a working kubernetes cluster (and you can host anything in it), whereas Azure App Service gives you a platform capable of doing x, y, and z specifically. this question boils down to why do I need kubernetes compared to VPS (I know App Service isn't a VPS exactly, but to simplify it).